# How to break the registry dependency?

Tags: c#, registry

I have a code which read some values from the registry.

How to break such a dependency? Here is a piece of code:

```
RegistryKey readKey = 
        Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\MyCompany\\MySoft");
```

Comment: `break such a dependency`? What?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible answers spring to mind

**1) A proxy service for the registry**

**e.g.**

```
public interface IRegistryService {
    string GetRegistrySubKey(string path);
}
```

The default implementation of the IRegistryService implements the given code and a mock can be injected into the unit under test for unit testing.

**2) Use [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) to mock the Registry class.**

A bit more work to set up. (Need to download and install and there is some project/test setup required) but it is a more general solution as Moles can be used to mock any of the BCL classes.

hth, 
Alan.

Answer (score 4):

You could pull configuration information out of the registry and into a configuration file, like `app.config`, for example.

Comment: +1 Registry is horrible place to store application configuration!

Comment: For unfortune I can not change it. Settings will be stored in the registry. I want to test a piece of code that work with values returned from the registry. So I need to break this dependency for the sake of testability.